# fetch an array of urls not recieving all data

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, fetch

I have an array of urls, I want to fetch every element of that array in order, but when I run the code I got the incorrect order, and some elements is missing

````js
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
const jsdom = require("jsdom");
const { JSDOM } = jsdom;
var chocolateList = [];
urlArray = [...] // 95 elements

urlArray.forEach((url, index) => {
  fetch(url).then(res => res.text())
    .then(async (success) => {
      const dom = new JSDOM(success); // convert response into DOM
      dom.window.document.querySelectorAll('h1')
        .forEach((htmlH1, i) => { //  get all h1 html tags
          if (htmlH1.includes('chocolate')) {
            chocolateList.push({name:htmlH1});
          }
        });
     console.log(chocolateList)
  })
});

```

outputs an array of approximately 20 elements instead of 95 elements

what im doing wrong?
````

Answer (score 1):

Try this code, it works. You made a few mistakes in the above, I explained it in the code comments section

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
const jsdom = require("jsdom");
const { JSDOM } = jsdom;
var chocolateList = [];
urlArray = ['https://www.example.com', 'https://www.example2.com'];

urlArray.forEach((url) => {
    fetch(url).then(res => res.text())
        .then(async (success) => {
            const dom = new JSDOM(success);
            //h1 tags array length
            let len = dom.window.document.querySelectorAll('h1').length;
            //h1 tags array
            let h1Arr = dom.window.document.querySelectorAll('h1');

            // Check for a length of an h1 tags array 
            if (len) {
                h1Arr.forEach((htmlH1, i) => {
                    let h1Text = htmlH1.textContent;
                    //The content that you are recieving is with lot of new-line and carriage return characters. 
                    //So, you should always sanitize the data before proceeding, and covert it to lower case as includes search is a case sensitive search
                    h1Text = h1Text.replace(/[\r\n]/g, '').trim().toLowerCase();
                    if (h1Text.includes('chocolate')) {
                        chocolateList.push({ name: htmlH1 });
                    }
                });
            } else {
                console.log('No h1 element present on DOM');
            }
            console.log(chocolateList);
        })
});
```